# Manage disk partitions

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS into an SSD (it previously had Kali, but I guess that doesn't matter), with the kernel 5.11.0-37-generic.

I have a problem: the computer doesn't turn off, it stays in the black, Ubuntu, shutting down screen, where it says:

```
... systemd[1]: Finished Power-Off.
... systemd[1]: Reached target Power-Off.
... systemd[1]: Shutting down.
```

and never shuts down.

So I checked other people's solutions, and one of them involved something with the swap partition. I checked the Disk Utility program and saw this:

[image: partitions]

Partition 2 is EFI type and is mounted in `/boot/efi`, which I guess it's for booting the system (I have Ubuntu in this disk and Windows in another separate disk).
Partition 5 is the Filesystem root.

My questions are:

1. Can I safely join partitions 3 and 5? Or remove partition 3?
2. Can I add the free space on the right to them?
3. Partition 1 is of type `W95 FAT32,` and the contents are `FAT (32-bit version) — Not Mounted`. Any idea why this partition was created for?

I guess this might not fix the shutting down problem, but it's a place to start.

Comment: Remove the part about your problem that the computer is not shutting down. It is not relevant here, because you are asking about something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I safely join partitions 3 and 5? Or remove partition 3?

No. Partition 3 is an extended partition, which holds the logical partition 5.

> Can I add the free space on the right to them?

This free space represents 1.1 MB, which is virtually nothing. Because partition sizes are restricted by some alignment rules, it may not be possible to expand partitions, but again: it is not worth the trouble.

> Partition 1 is of type W95 FAT32, and the contents are FAT (32-bit version) — Not Mounted. Any idea why this àrtition was created for?

You probably did not erase the full disk and have the Ubuntu installer repartition the entire drive. This Partition 1 probably is a leftover from earlier installations, and may also have been an EFI patition, which currently is not used.